# how to identify whether a dataset is structured or unstructured

Tags: machine-learning, data-structures, dataset, bigdata

I am planning to do some useful task on my raw dataset (any, if it is big data) using machine learning with big data. So how can I identify a collected dataset is structured, unstructured etc. Suggest some techniques or steps for my query. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structured data is organized based on either model or schema. Querying or performing any other operations on data are straightforward (using query languages).

If 
 1. Your model or schema is not helping you to perform the basic operations.
 2. You are required to spend more time on basic analysis
you can categorized them as unstructured data.

Unstructured data is not organized (not always), best example is human languages, you will be required to use NLP, text mining or any other processing tools to perform operations on it.

Answer (score 1):

Big data is almost always unstructured. If a data set is clean and tidy enough to analyze with traditional analysis tools, like the out-of-the-box ones in excel, it's probably not 'Big'. Big Data tends to be a big, unstructured mess. That's why people hire analysts and data scientists.